# What is wrong in my ajax code to display comment live?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here I have a form to submit comment, `.disp` `div` that displays comments and ajax code that sends data to comments.php which inserts data into database. Here ajax code sends data but does not `prepends` comment live. I have to refresh page to see comment. Means data is inserted but only live displaying of comment does not work. jQuery library is included.

```
<form method='post' name='form' action=''>
    <input type='text' name='comment' id='comment' placeholder='Write a comment....' /><br />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' />
</form>

<div class='disp'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src='<?php echo $row['pic']; ?>'/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href='<?php echo $row['username']; ?>'><?php echo $row['name'] ?></a>
                <p><?php echo $row['comment']; ?></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    ("#submit").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
        var comment = $("#comment").val();
        var post = '<?php echo $postid ?>';
        var dataString = 'comment=' + comment + '&post=' + post;

        if (comment == '') {
            alert('Please Give Valid Details');
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "comment.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                error: function(xhr, status, error) { var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")"); console.log(err.Message); }
                    $(".disp").prepend(html);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: This may not fix the immediate problem, but you should really change your code to `var comment = encodeURIComponent( $("#comment").val() );` otherwise, characters in the user input may goober up your data string. Like if the supplied value were say `&some input` for example

Comment: ^ or better yet, provide the data parameter in an object so that jQuery takes care of the encoding for you.

Comment: Also, if you are not already, be aware of [Cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and be sure to filter your user supplied data before inserting into your database ; )

Comment: If you put `console.log(html);`  right before `$(".disp").prepend(html);` what gets printed in the console? There may be an issue with how you are returning the data from your `php` script

Comment: @DelightedD0D did that nothing happened

Comment: Add this after your success function `,
     error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
    console.log(err.Message);
     }` what do you get now?

Comment: @DelightedD0D page is automatically refreshed on submitting form but no data is inserted now

Comment: Can you update the above to show how you added it, that should not happen

Comment: Wait, your form is getting submitted before the ajax gets called, you need to prevent that,  change `$("#submit").click(function() {`  to `$("#submit").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();` what happens now?

Comment: @DelightedD0D updated code,  still page refreshing and no data inserted

Comment: Your placement of the error function is not quite right, see https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/4Lbo23h6/ for the correct format